# windows 7 don't include .net 3.5 why?

Tags: windows, .net-3.5

i set up windows 7 two days ago. But i downloaded .net framework 3.5 . i think windows 7 included .net 3.5

Comment: "windows 7 don’t support .net 3.5 why?"
"Header is clear. But i need to learn why windows 7 includes .net 3.5? So i set up .net 3.5 in windows 7."

Correct me if im wrong but arent you saying 2 diffrent things here?

Comment: Do you mean runtime (included) or SDK (not included)?

Comment: Not strictly a useful queastion now is it. If you want to howl microsoft try there forums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is not very clear! But Windows 7 comes with .NET 3.5 pre-installed. I installed an application on it a couple of days ago that requires .NET 3.5 and didn't need to install anything first.